# Using a main Global resource file to handle all translations

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, globalization

I have a ASP.Net website that has a App-GlobalResources structure as follows:

[image: App-GlobalResources structure]

I'm using this file to retrieve the required localized strings in my markup as follows:

```
  <%@ Page Title='<%$ Resources:ResourceStaticStuff, HelpIntroductionTitle %>' Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/App_Resources/PlainDefault.master" 
           AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Introduction.aspx.cs" Inherits="Software.PasswordReset.Registration.Web.Help.Introduction" %>

  <asp:Content ID="ContentWelcome" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContentPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <h1 class="title-regular clearfix">
      <asp:Literal ID="LiteralHeader" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources:ResourceStaticStuff, HelpIntroductionTitle %>' />
    </h1>
    <asp:Literal ID="LiteralHelp" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources:ResourceStaticStuff, HelpIntroductionLiteralHelpText %>' />
    <br />
    <br />
  </asp:Content>
```

I'm always getting the default English text even after changing the culture + ui culture. I'm changing the culture at runtime as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      SiteLogger.NLogger.Info("Loading Languages and Directories");

      if (!LoadLanguages() || !LoadDirectories())
      {
        SiteLogger.NLogger.Info("Loading Languages or Directories failed!");
        return;
      }

      SiteLogger.NLogger.Info("Completed : PublicLogOn.PageLoad");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    SiteLogger.NLogger.Error("Error in PublicLogOn.Page_Load", ex.Message);
  }

}

private Boolean LoadLanguages()
{
  Boolean methodResult;
  try
  {
    SiteLogger.NLogger.Info("In Load Languages");
    DDLLanguages.Items.Clear();
    var fetchedLanguages = UserManagePage.GetOrganizationLanguages();

    foreach (var oneFetchedLanguage in fetchedLanguages)
    {
      DDLLanguages.Items.Add(new ListItem(oneFetchedLanguage.LanguageSymbol, oneFetchedLanguage.LanguageSymbol));
    }

    if (fetchedLanguages.Count() == 1)
    {
      DDLLanguages.Enabled = false;
    }

    // The first place where the language is pushed in. Everything that follows afterwards will be translated
    Session["UserLanguage"] = DDLLanguages.SelectedValue;
    UpdateLanguage();

    methodResult = true;
  }
  catch (Exception exp)
  {
    SiteLogger.NLogger.Error("Error in load languages : ", exp.ToString());
    // Nlogger.LogError(exp);
    labelMessage.Text = MessageFormatter.GetFormattedErrorMessage("Error retrieving organization languages.");
    methodResult = false;
  }

  return methodResult;
}

private void UpdateLanguage(String languageCode="")
{
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(languageCode))
  {
    languageCode = Session["UserLanguage"].ToString();
  }

  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(languageCode);
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(languageCode);

  var isRtl = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft;

  if (isRtl)
  {
    Master.BodyTag.Attributes["dir"] = "rtl";
  }
  else
  {
    Master.BodyTag.Attributes["dir"] = "ltr";
  }

  base.InitializeCulture();
}

protected void DDLLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Session["UserLanguage"] = DDLLanguages.SelectedValue;
  UpdateLanguage();
}
```

Thing of interest here is that the page becomes Right-To-Left or Left-To-Right good and proper but with English. So, it'd seem the *.ur-PK.resx are not being entertained.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the culture and UI culture for an ASP.NET Web page programmatically `override the InitializeCulture method for the page`.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    if (Session["UserLanguage"] != null)
    {
        String selectedLanguage = Session["UserLanguage"].ToString();
        UICulture = selectedLanguage ;
        Culture = selectedLanguage ;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new 
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

source:-[Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

To fix this, you could create a BasePage that all your specific pages inherit:

1. Create a new Class (not Webform), call it BasePage, or whatever you
   want.
2. Make it inherit System.Web.UI.Page.
3. Make all your other pages inherit the BasePage.

Here's an example:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        //Do the logic you want for all pages that inherit the BasePage.
    }
}
```

And the specific pages should look something like this:

```
public partial class _Default : BasePage //Instead of it System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your logic.
    }

    //Your logic.
}
```

Comment: Okay. But upon switching to a different page, I fallback to Eng again. Is this to be repeated on every page?

Comment: I already did that as it was the only viable solution. Testing it out.

Comment: I don't know why but as soon as I change a language on one of the page to, let's say, ur-PK, That page and the other pages become blank. Except the MasterPage stuff. I'll deal with MasterPage later but I need to fix this blank issue. The resources are there and loaded properly. Don't know how the localization DLLs are being generated.

Comment: I wonder if I do this at MasterPage level instead of Inheriting custom BaseWebForm